# Dictionary data was printed in non-JSON style

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I have a dictionary which I convert to JSON but when I print it out I have back slashes which makes it difficult to get it as NSDictionary. 
Below is my code:

```
let postParameters = ["action":"check","msis":"343","username":"username,"os":"ios"]
```

Then I use `postParameters` trying to convert to JSON.

```
if let jsonParameters = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParameters, options: .prettyPrinted) {
    let theJSONText = String(data: jsonParameters,encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print("JSON string = \(theJSONText)")
}
```

Now when I print out the JSON, it comes formatted as next:

```
JSON string = Optional("{\n  \"action\" : \"check\",\n  \"os\" : \"ios\",\n  \"msis\" : \"343\",\n  \"username\" : \"username\"\n}")
```

Now my question is how should I convert my dictionary to have a JSON with no backslash and `\n`.

Comment: the conversion is correct and it's a valid json string

Comment: `prettyPrinted` will be giving you carriage returns

Comment: Your code is fine (other than needing to properly unwrap `theJSONText`). It's just the resulting using `print`.

Comment: @SteveO'Connor carriage returns?

Comment: @chevi99 Sorry I meant new line which is the `\n` control character also known as carriage return line feed.

Comment: @maddy Thanks for the adds-on i figured anytime I print out something to the console even if I have done my optional binding I still see the the word optional attached to it. But according to your explanation it is because I'm concatenating it with a string ryt?

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your code to use optional binding to unwrap your `theJSONText` string, it works as expected:

```
if let jsonParameters = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParameters, options: .prettyPrinted),
    let theJSONText = String(data: jsonParameters, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("JSON string = \(theJSONText)")
}
```

That displays:

```
JSON string = {
  "os" : "ios",
  "msis" : "343",
  "action" : "check",
  "username" : "username"
}
```